# "Stumble" and "tumble" 

Tags: etymology, synonyms

Take the word *tumble* - by prefixing it with a single letter you get a whole new word *stumble* with a slightly different meaning.

When it occurred to me I tried thinking of other words like this but could not find any. Is this unique to this pair of words then? Also, any history of this pair of words will be welcome.

Comment: Running out of ideas for the Sunday puzzle, Will Shortz, or did you put Liane Hansen up to this?

Comment: @MetaEd just curious that's all.

Comment: Rumble & crumble, rest & wrest, lay & slay... I don't think there's anything remarkable about such "pairs".

Comment: I think OP is asking about pairs of words which also have a related or compatible meaning. *Rumble* and *crumble* (or *crumble* and *tumble*) seem to fit the bill.

Comment: @onomatomaniak was just about to say what MetaEd said - I also never said it's very remarkable, just curious if *unique*..

Comment: Crunch & scrunch, crimp & scrimp, lather & slather, amble & ramble. I agree with @onomatomaniak - nothing of great significance here.

Comment: ...and if you want related *meanings*, onomatomaniak should have said *rumble & grumble*.

Answer (score 3):

When two words differ by only one sound they are called *minimal pairs*. For a list, see [here](http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/wordscape/wordlist/). I can't find the pair *stumble / tumble* in the list. That may be because the addition of a sound, rather than its replacement, may be a special case, or there may be a different term for them of which I am unaware.

Answer (score 1):

In the style of Will Shortz:

> Signs of a fever: *ache* and *shake*
>
> Looking up: *eye* and *high*
>
> Sea creatures: *eel* and *seal*
>
> Give props: *shout out*
>
> Have dinner at table: *eat* at your *seat*
>
> Petroleum spill: *oil soil*
>
> Metal packaging: *in* a *tin*
>
> Medicine accident: *pill spill*
>
> Misspeak: *lip slip*
>
> Brown Christmas: *no snow*
>
> Birds do it: *wing swing*
>
> In the groin: *low blow*
>
> Also in the groin: *love glove*

A shout out to my source: [speech-language-therapy dot com](http://www.speech-language-therapy.com/wordlists.html)